# jQuery / Javascript - Is it possible to get the next call in the chain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen the `.filter()` and `.end()` calls in a chain which leads me to believe that this is possible. So I've made my own function that can be added to the chain `rawr()`

```
$('#object').fadeIn().rawr().delay(1000).fadeOut();
```

I want rawr() to see what is coming up next and depending on what it is, allow execution to continue or to end the chain and move to the next line of code. How is this done?

Comment: If I understood your question, you need to manipulate the queue : http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: @dystroy - I was thinking of not having this only deal with animations. So if I was chaining any function calls how could I see the next one?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to see what is next, only before.

Comment: That's not how `.filter()` and `.end()` work.

Comment: @zzzzBov is correct, Filter leaves a trace stack of the original DOM elements that are restored by calling `.end`. Traversing of chained methods is not possible.

Comment: @Austin, you might want to change your question to be relevant to the problem you're having. It sounds like you need to look at [`.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue), [`.dequeue`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue), and [`clearQueue`](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue). If you use `.queue` to check what's in the list of queued functions, you'd be able to clear the queue before dequeuing the `fx` queue.

Comment: @zzzzBov - .queue only works for animations, right? I was thinking more along the lines of chaining non-animation functions together and seeing how I could manipulate those.

Comment: @Aust, `queue` works with any queued asynchronous functions. Animations happen to fall into that category because they use the `fx` queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the next jQuery function in the chain of called functions directly without parsing the JavaScript source itself.

Given your comment:

> I was thinking of not having this only deal with animations.

You'll want to use the [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue) method to store a function in the `fx` queue. When the custom function is executed, the `fx` queue will have queued all the animations in the jQuery chain.

Within your custom function you'd be able to access the `fx` queue and check what's been queued. You'd also be able to call [`clearQueue`](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue) to remove any of the queued functions before dequeuing the `fx` queue.

It's necessary to dequeue the custom queued function as the `fx` queue wont continue for any other queued functions until the currently executing function has indicated that it's finished.

That all being said, it sounds like you should break your chain and conditionally execute methods, rather than trying to chain animations that are simply cleared later.

Comment: So hypothetically, if I have a chain that has to deal with animations, I use `queue` with the fx. But if I have a chain that does not deal with animations, I just create my own queue?

Comment: @Aust, that would work. I find it to be rare that I need a custom queue for anything, although most of the async stuff that I work on involves animations occurring.

Comment: Thanks a lot you have been a great help to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Conditionally ending a chain is possible, look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jquery-en/8NIIcn0qyxw).

```
$.fn.if = function(flag) {
    return (flag) ? this.pushStack( this ) : this.pushStack( [] );
};
```

Looking ahead of the current item in the chain, however, is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how `.filter` and `.end` work. Right from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/end/):

> When this happens, it is as if the new set of elements is pushed onto
>   a stack that is maintained inside the object. Each successive
>   filtering method pushes a new element set onto the stack. If we need
>   an older element set, we can use end() to pop the sets back off of the
>   stack.